# How to increment serial number while using pagination in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I need one help .i am using Angular.js `dirPagination.js`for pagination of my table data but here my problem is suppose i fixed item per page is 5,the first 5 items is coming with serial no `1,2,3,4,5` but for second page again the serial no is starting from 1.I am adding my code below.

```
<tr dir-paginate="pro in ($parent.labelResults=(productDataList  | filter:searchProduct)) | itemsPerPage:5" current-page="currentPage">
<td>{{itemsPerPage *(currentPage-1)+$index+1}}</td>
<td>{{pro.Product_name}}</td>
<td><img ng-src="upload/{{pro.image}}" name="pro" border="0" style="width:50px; height:50px; border:#808080 1px solid;" /></td>
<td>{{pro.Discount}}</td>
<td>{{pro.Offer}}</td>
<td>{{pro.unit_cost_price}}</td>
<td>{{pro.unit_sale_price}}</td>
<td>{{pro.quantity}}</td>
<td>{{pro.shipping_charge}}</td>                                                  
</tr>   
<div class="pull-right">
<dir-pagination-controls  max-size="5"  direction-links="true"  boundary-links="true" >
 </dir-pagination-controls>
</div>
```

Here for each page of pagination the serial no is starting from 1.Here i need from the first page the serial no should starts from 1 and it should continue like `1,2,3....`so on.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Consider Page Number as well...

Comment: @RayonDabre: not getting you.Can you please give any solution?

Comment: If I read you right, If there are 5 items in each page and 10 items in total, you expect `6,7,8..` in the next page right ?

Comment: It could be achieved using `(ITEMS_PER_PAGE * (CURRENT_PAGE-1)) + $index+1`

Comment: Where i will write this.Can you edit your answer in my code please?

Comment: Can you share a Plunker demo ? `{{pageSize * (currentPage-1)+$index+1}}` will help!

Comment: Ok,I am trying to make a plunkr.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/PA0OvtTy7r8xlN4Rr5sk?p=preview

Comment: i did it its coming NAN in serial no place

Comment: Did you go though shared Plunker ?

Comment: yes,i am updatimg my code again ..wait.

Comment: I am unable to execute this code..Plunker will make sense...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107501/discussion-between-satya-and-rayon-dabre).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Could be achieved using `(ITEMS_PER_PAGE * (CURRENT_PAGE-1)) + $index+1`

```
<tr dir-paginate="pro in users | itemsPerPage:itemsPerPage" current-page="currentPage"> 
<td>{{itemsPerPage *(currentPage-1)+$index+1}}</td> 
<td>{{pro.first_name}}</td> 
<td>{{pro.last_name}}</td> 
<td>{{pro.hobby}}</td> 
</tr>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.currentPage=1;
$scope.itemsPerPage=5;
```

Sample [Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/PA0OvtTy7r8xlN4Rr5sk?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for this awesome Answer. I tried many things, but only your solution is working. It helps me to show custom Pagination